# Should HTTP or HTTPS be used in hyperlinks?

Tags: http, https, hyperlink, redirect

I am building a SAAS product which runs over HTTPS. It is all set up to automatically redirect any requests coming in over HTTP to the HTTPS equivalent.

When I link to the site, both internally (e.g: navbar & footer) and externally (e.g: sharing landing page link), should the links be HTTP or HTTPS links?

I would have thought HTTPS but plenty of others (i.e: GitHub and other SAAS products) use HTTP links and let the site redirect to HTTPS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been shown that redirects in general are bad as it makes an additional call to the server. Being that you are running sass you always want to run the least amount of hops to reduce server load. If your sass is on https always use https. If this is an seo question there is a advantage in search algorithms for https over http, but that could open up a discussion that is not necessary . So in short always use the shortest hops possible as this reduces server load even if it is minuscule.